# Address register offsets and analysis (Tricore)

Tags: ida, offset

I'm decompiling a binary file for a Infineon Tricore processor, the code is incomplete and only contains part of the code so will not execute. The auto analysis did a great job and the code is readable but I have 1 snag with the address offsets.

Currently a large part of the code uses a static address offset which are set into [a0]. I know this to be a value of 0xd0008000 and it never changes but can't figure out a way of forcing this during the analysis.

For example, the code will load an address register like this:
[a0]0x50f0
I know this should should be 0xd000d0f0 but the auto analysis will just show [a0]0x50f0.

I can force each reference on a local basis by hitting Ctrl+R and manually adding the offset but I'm interested to know what the correct method is.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Looks like you need to find the equivalent copy_block that tells you where 0xd0008000 was copied to.

Comment: @Unicornux Thanks, that turned out to be the solution!

Comment: Did you figure out a nice way to do this?